# css dropdown menu positioning

Tags: html, css

Can someone take a look at my drop-down menu i'm having trouble with some child elements. The problem is with the .sublevel category. It's twofold, the first is i'm having to position it absolutely which could be a problem, since i'd have to update it every time i need it to move to a different element.

The second is obviously the fact that it's not displaying right and i'm not exactly sure why.

Here is the JSfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ynwtN/3/

transiton code not working either:

```
#cssmenu .sublevel:hover > ul{
      padding: 18px 26px;
      left:170px;
      top: 200px;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      font-size: 13px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      width: 150px;
      border-left: 4px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #c28130;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(151, 99, 33, .43);
}
```

Comment: are you referring to the problem occured when selecting product 4?

Comment: Yes the 3rd level drop-down menu if you will.

Comment: i just modified your code and posted below... check that...
demo:http://jsfiddle.net/ynwtN/5/

Answer (score 0):

i edited your code....

try this....

```
  #cssmenu .sublevel:hover > ul{
    padding: 18px 26px;
    left:155px;
     top: 150px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 150px;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #c28130;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(151, 99, 33, .43);

}
```